# Point 1 domain to 2 different DNS

Tags: nameserver, domain-name

Is it possible for a domain name to point to 2 (or more) different name-server? For example, here I have a domain name `testdomain.net`, and I want to point it to

- ns65.domaincontrol.com (GoDaddy Name-server)
- ns66.domaincontrol.com (GoDaddy Name-server)
- eva.ns.cloudflare.com (CloudFlare Name-server)
- igor.ns.cloudflare.com (CloudFlare Name-server)

On the GoDaddy, the records aren't going to be the same as the records on the CloudFlare so this setup is not for HA purpose. The reason is that: I switched to CloudFlare 2 days ago and I noticed that when I tried to open a website hosted on my server on the non-standard port (e.g., I have OwnCloud on port 3387), I couldn't access it unless I switched back to GoDaddy name-server.

Ideally, records on the CloudFlare name-server will point to service(s) on standard port...

```
A blog.testdomain.net 192.0.0.1
```

with the vHost file mapping that domain to a web-standard port, the `80`. While on the GoDaddy name-server...

```
A owncloud.testdomain.net 192.0.0.2
```

... with the vHost file mapping that domain to a non-standard port, the `3387`.

Could this be done that way?

Comment: It really isn't clear to me what you are expecting here?  How are you expecting a random server on the Internet to pick the 'right' DNS server?

Comment: While the user may seem confused, his goals seem simple: Serve `owncloud.testdomain.net` directly and utilize cloudFlare's services for `blog.testdomain.net`.

Comment: @Zoredache which is why I already said that this is not a HA setup.

Comment: @lVlint67 If that is what he is wanting, then I am glad you saw the question and answered it.  I certainly didn't see that as what he was asking in my initial quick read of the question.

Comment: You can do this perfectly well within CloudFlare's DNS control panel. Just click the orange cloud so that it turns gray, and requests for that name will bypass CloudFlare and go directly.

Answer (score 2):

CloudFlare is not going to work properly with the nameservers set like that. CloudFlare has to be in positions 1 &2; the other nameservers have to be removed.

"e.g., I have OwnCloud on port 3387), I couldn't access it unless I switched back to GoDaddy name-server."

CloudFlare can only proxy certain [web ports](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-CloudFlare-work-with-). Ports not on web traffic records should be on a subdomain we don't touch in your DNS settings.

Answer (score 1):

Um... I think what you need is:

```
blog.testdomain.net   NS  eva.ns.cloudflare.com
blog.testdomain.net   NS  igor.ns.cloudflare.com

owncloud.testdomain.net  IN  A  192.0.0.2
```

EG:

1. point the `NS` records for `testdomain.net` to `ns65.domaincontrol.com` and `ns66.domaincontrol.com`
2. Set an `A` record for `owncloud.testdomain.net` as `192.0.0.2` at domaincontrol
3. Create the `NS` records for the `subdomain` `blog.testdomain.net` to point to the `cloudflare` DNs servers

** *Note the lack of `A` records for blog.testdomain.net in the domaincontrol zone*

I've never used Godaddy DNS because a few years ago **all** of the public free DNS providers stopped allowing customization and control of things. I don't know if godaddy supports this kind of stuff but it is trivial to setup if you run your own DNS.

Comment: I will report you back this weekend. On GoDaddy we do have the option to add NS record. https://i.imgur.com/UGYTeWr.png

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I understand what you are trying to do, and I would strongly caution against it. Recursive servers will rotate between the different DNS servers for the zone, and their clients will only get the records that are known by the server they reached. Because of this, your customers will get different answers each time, and the results will be inconsistent. In essence, at any point in time, your customers will experience the equivalent of half your servers being unreachable at all. If you have your DNS served by two providers, you will either need to ensure that you manually keep the zones synchronized (this is error-prone, and you will cause an outage) or you will need to subordinate all the servers except one, put all your records in that one Master server, configure all the others as Slave servers, setup AXFR from the Master to all the Slaves, and setup notifications from the Master to all the Slaves.

I was the DNS hostmaster at a Fortune 200 Financial Services firm several years ago, and I have seen setups like you described, to try and prevent a single point failure, only to introduce horrific service-impacting outages that were hard to diagnose.

Comment: Just curious why this was downvoted. Feedback would be great.

Comment: Might be because it doesn't really grasp the content of the question correctly: the user wants to use CloudFlare, and your alleged Fortune 200 stories with broken DNS have little to do with that.